# A simple recursion function prints weird stuff

Tags: c, recursion

So I need to code a recursive function that validates if the number is a prime number.
The algorithm is pretty simple and works correctly, it's just that when I print the function rather than showing 1 or 0 it shows random crap (maybe addresses?) and I couldn't find out why.

The code:

```
int isPrimal(int n, int p) {
    if (p == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n % p == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    isPrimal(n, p - 1);
    printf("n = %d i = %d\n", n, p);    
}

int main() {
    int numcase, *A, sizeA = 0, i = 0, cnt3dig = 0, n, p;

    printf("Enter a number to check for primality\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    p = (n - 1);
    printf("The result is 1 if the number is a prime, 0 otherwise\n");
    isPrimal(n, p);
    printf("The result is %d\n", isPrimal);
}
```

Comment: Why do you ignore the return value of `scanf()`. If `n` is not initialized at the `scanf()` you will never know and follow using it at `p = (n - 1)` which makes `p` contents undeterminate and then you call `isPrimal()`.

Comment: The answers I see (two of them) address your first, immediate problem, but you'll shortly find some more.  Your function doesn't always return a value, so you sometimes get garbage returned.  It is also an extremely inefficient way to determine the primality of a number.  I'm not sure you could safely use it on even the biggest 32-bit signed integer, let alone anything bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the address of the `isPrimal()` function, you should change it to

```
printf("The result is %d\n", isPrimal(n, p));
```

and don't forget to check `scanf()`'s return value.

Answer (score 3):

The `printf` in `main` invokes undefined behavior because you pass the address of the function `isPrimal` instead of its result: change `printf("The result is %d\n", isPrimal);` to

```
printf("The result is %d\n", isPrimal(n, p));
```

Furthermore, your algorithm is very inefficient.  Function `isPrimal` calls itself recursively `n-2` times.  If you remove the `printf` statement, the compiler notices the tail call to itself and turns this recursion into a loop.  When you have the `printf` statement it cannot do this and for large values of `n` you probably recurse too deep and cause a `Stackoverflow`.

Answer (score 1):

```
There are 2 changes that are necessary
```

1. In main, While printing the output make a function call -not a reference to the location of the function.
2. In isPrimal, Call the isprimal recursively after the print statement.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
  int isPrimal(int n, int p) {
    if (p == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n % p == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("n = %d i = %d\n", n, p);
    isPrimal(n, p - 1);
}

int main() {
    int numcase, *A, sizeA = 0, i = 0, cnt3dig = 0, n, p;

    printf("Enter a number to check for primality\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    p = (n - 1);
    printf("The result is 1 if the number is a prime, 0 otherwise\n");

    printf("The result is %d\n", isPrimal(n, p));
    return 1;
}
```